# Transmitting I2S mic data over UART in STM32

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, nucleo

I have interfaced I2S mic (ICS-43434) with STM32f401RET6 board.

I have wired it correctly, now just trying to test the mic by passing the data through UART to my pc. Hoping someone can point me in the correct direction.

I have tried passing straight to the UART transmit. However I think I may need some datahandling - I am receiving from the UART, but sometimes just 0 or other times just gibberish which is not from the Mic as it still transmits even when i disconnect the mic.

I2S mic is receiving data in 24 bits in 32 bit frame, the last 8 bits are junk. The protocol is Big Endian, I am thinking that the HAL library handles this, however I am not completely sure.

```
uint16_t data;
   while (1)
  {
      /*USER CODE END WHILE */
       HAL_StatusTypeDef result= HAL_I2S_Receive(&hi2s1,&data,2,100);
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,&data,2,100);
       /*USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
 /*USER CODE END 3 */
```

What did I miss?

Comment: I believe the 'size' parameter to `HAL_I2S_Receive()` indicates the number of 16-bit values to receive, not the number of bytes. So you either need `uint16_t data[2]`, or set the receive size to one. However, transferring the data in tiny chunks like this is going to be a problem, you'll no doubt end up losing data on the I2S while you are transmitting on the UART.

Comment: Also, you should always check the return values from HAL functions. They are good at telling you if something isn't right.